# how to iterate over certain rows based on condition to calculate cosine distance

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that look like below. Notice that the index is not sequential.

```
pd.DataFrame(np.array([[0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 1], [0.4, 0.5, 0, 0], [0.2, 0.4, 0.2,0],[0.3, 0.1, 0.2,1],[0.4, 0.2, 0.2,1]]),
                       columns=['a', 'b', 'c','manager'])
df=df.set_index([pd.Index([0, 2, 10, 14,16])], 'id')
```

[image]

I would like to calculate the cosine distance between each row and those that have 1 in `manager` (excluding itself), and then take an average and append it to a new column `cos_distance`. For example, for row0, I will get cosine distance with row 3 and 4 and then take the average. How do I add the condition to restrict it to those with 1 in the manager column only?

I tried running below code, but probably because we don't have sequential indices, it returned an empty list.

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine as cos
x=df.iloc[:, :3]
manager=df[df['manager']==1].iloc[:, :3]
lead_cos = []
for i in range(0):
    person_cos = []
    for j in range(0, len(manager)):
        person_cos.append(cos(x.loc[i], manager.loc[j]))
    lead_cos.append(np.average(person_cos))
lead_cos
```

Desired output:
[image]

Comment: Please add a sample output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I'm trying. I'm not getting the exact values as your desired output, probably because for each "manager" I include itself in the cosine calculation (maybe you need to avoid that too, not sure).

EDIT: I manage to avoid repeating the current manager. However, index 14 gives me a value different than yours. I also included rounding to 2 decimal places.

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine as cos
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 1], [0.4, 0.5, 0, 0], [0.2, 0.4, 0.2,0],[0.3, 0.1, 0.2,1],[0.4, 0.2, 0.2,1]]),
                       columns=['a', 'b', 'c','manager'])

df=df.set_index([pd.Index([0, 2, 10, 14,16])], 'id')

n = df.shape[0]

x=df.iloc[:, :3]

manager=df[df['manager']==1].iloc[:, :3]
n_man = manager.shape[0]

lead_cos = []
for i in range(n):
    person_cos = []
    for j in range(n_man):
        if x.index[i] != manager.index[j]:
            person_cos.append(cos(x.values.tolist()[i], manager.values.tolist()[j]))
    lead_cos.append(round(np.average(person_cos),2))

df['lead_cos'] = lead_cos
print(df)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thanks! How can we remove itself from being counted?

Comment: I did it with `if x.index[i] != manager.index[j]:`
Updated the answer